# Save attachments from specified subject in specific Inbox subfolder

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-filter

I would like to setup a VBA to automatically download attachments from unread emails with the subject `"Shipment MTD"` in the sub-folder `Inbox\Reports` and save them to the following folder `C:\My Documents\Daily Shipments`

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolderpath As String
    Dim strDeletedFiles As String
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim sName As String

    ' Get the path to your My Documents folder
    strFolderpath = "C:\My Documents\Daily Shipment"
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Reports")
    Set myTasks = Fldr.Items

    ' Select unread items with required subject line
    Set resultItems = myTasks.Restrict("[UnRead] = False AND [Subject] = ""Shipment MTD""")

    ' Get the collection of selected objects.
    Set objSelection = resultItems

    ' The attachment folder needs to exist
    ' You can change this to another folder name of your choice

    ' Set the Attachment folder.
    strFolderpath = strFolderpath & "\Daily Shipment\"

    ' Select attachements in messsage
    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments

    ' Check each selected item for attachments.

    For Each resultItems In myTasks
        lngCount = objAttachments.Count

        If lngCount > 0 Then

            dtDate = objMsg.SentOn
            sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "hhnnss", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" 'include DTS

            For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

                ' Get the file name.
                strFile = sName & objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
                ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
                strFile = strFolderpath & strFile

                ' Save the attachment as a file.
                objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

            Next i
        End If

    Next

ExitSub:

        Set objAttachments = Nothing
        Set objMsg = Nothing
        Set objSelection = Nothing
        Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

I want to select only the unread emails in the reports folder. It seems that VBA is not selecting this correctly.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you are you trying to do this through [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) instead of directly from [outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba)?  (Also, you have forgotten to declare a *lot* of variables, such as `MyTasks` or `olApp`)

Comment: How many `Items` are in `resultItems`?  (Try `MsgBox resultItems.Count`)  Your DASL query will be looking for subjects that *exactly* match "Shipment MTD", no "Re: Shipment MTD" or "Shipment MTD - 2018-01-01" allowed.

Comment: Hi chronocidal, actually it’s in outlook-vba. In terms of the subject, I think it’s alright because the daily emails contain exactly the same subject. I’ll look at declaring all my variables again.

Comment: Re variables:  Always use [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement) - you can turn it on by default from the options menu. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here is better filter that will filter by Subject, unread and items with attachments only, also your code has lots errors*

*Here is after cleanup, short and simple*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
    ' Get the path to your My Documents folder
    Dim strFolderpath As String
        strFolderpath = "C:\Documents\Temp\"

    ' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim Fldr As Outlook.Folder
    Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Flash Orders")

    Dim Filter As String
        Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                           Chr(34) & " Like '%Shipment MTD%' AND " & _
                           Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & _
                           Chr(34) & "=1 AND " & _
                           Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:read" & _
                           Chr(34) & "=0"

    Dim myTasks As Outlook.Items
    Set myTasks = Fldr.Items.Restrict(Filter)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object

    For i = myTasks.Count To 1 Step -1
        If myTasks(i).Class = olMail Then
            Set objMsg = myTasks(i)

            Dim dtDate As Date
                dtDate = objMsg.SentOn
            Dim sName As String
                sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & _
                        Format(dtDate, "hhnnss", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem)

            Dim strFile As String
            Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
            For Each objAttachment In objMsg.Attachments
                ' Get the file name.
                strFile = strFolderpath & sName & "-" & objAttachment.FileName
                Debug.Print strFile
                ' Save the attachment as a file.
                objAttachment.SaveAsFile strFile
            Next
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```